# Bind jQuery to multiple instances of a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am currently using the "SwipeJS" plugin (https://github.com/bradbirdsall/Swipe) to create a photo slider.

Following is the code for the div. I have MULTIPLE instances of this div on a single page (below am using 2 div's only.

```
        <div id='slider1' class='swipe'>
          <div class='swipe-wrap'>
            <div class="swipe_index"><img src="/images/default/business.jpg" alt="/images/default/business.jpg" id="img1_1" width="100" height ="100" / >   </div>
            <div class="swipe_index"><img src="/images/default/News.jpg" alt="/images/default/News.jpg" id="img1_2" width="100" height ="100" / >  </div>
            <div class="swipe_index"><img src="/images/default/Gaming.jpg" alt="/images/default/Gaming.jpg" id="img1_3" width="100" height ="100" / > </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <span class="nav prev">Prev</span>
        <span class="nav next">Next</span>  
        <span class="nav now">now</span>    

        <div id='slider2' class='swipe'>
          <div class='swipe-wrap'>
            <div class="swipe_index"><img src="/images/default/business.jpg" alt="/images/default/business.jpg" id="img1_1" width="100" height ="100" / >   </div>
            <div class="swipe_index"><img src="/images/default/News.jpg" alt="/images/default/News.jpg" id="img1_2" width="100" height ="100" / >  </div>
            <div class="swipe_index"><img src="/images/default/Gaming.jpg" alt="/images/default/Gaming.jpg" id="img1_3" width="100" height ="100" / > </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <span class="nav prev">Prev</span>
        <span class="nav next">Next</span>  
        <span class="nav now">now</span>
```

I am not aware as to how to bind the following jquery code to every instance of the div. Below is my attempt to modify the jquery

```
            <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('.swipe').each(function(){
                    Slider = $(this).Swipe({
                        continuous: false,
                        stopPropagation: true,
                        callback: function(index, elem) {
                            alert(index);
                        },
                    }).data('Swipe');

                    $('.next').click(function(data){ 
                        Slider.next();
                        //alert($(".swipe_index .current").data('index'));

                    });

                    $('.prev').on('click', Slider.prev);
                });
            });

            </script>
```

However, the above code doesn't work well. This only binds the jquery to the last div.Can someone please help correct the code above?

Whats the best way to bind jquery to multiple instances of divs on a webpage.

Comment: Are you sure the plugin works with multiple instances on the same page ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.swipe').each(function () {
        //create a closure variable instead of a global one
        var Slider = $(this).Swipe({
            continuous: false,
            stopPropagation: true,
            callback: function (index, elem) {
                alert(index);
            },
        }).data('Swipe');

        //use relative tranversal to find the next/prev elements
        $(this).next().next('.next').click(function (data) {
            Slider.next();
            //alert($(".swipe_index .current").data('index'));

        });

        //try using $.proxy
        $(this).next('.prev').on('click', $.proxy(Slider.prev, Slider));
    });
});
```

Comment: to be clear, the issue is `Slider = $(this).Swipe({` declares a global var that all instances share. adding `var` causes it to be a local var that they do not share.

Comment: Note, this still has an issue, you will have 2 events on each next and prev el.

Comment: @KevinB yes missed that

Comment: @ArunPJohny thanks for your responses. I have now marked this as answered. works perfect! Thanks again.

Comment: @KevinB Thanks to you too, mate :)